# Kafka topic deletion

Tags: java, apache-kafka, integration-testing

I use Kafka as an event store for an Event Sourcing system.

In the integration tests, I delete all the topics currently available in Kafka by running

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic <topic-name>
```

for each existing topic, to make sure that the "old" data does not affect the following tests.

I'm aware that the topics are only marked for deletion, but not deleted in place. And, in most cases, it's OK for me.

But in some test cases, a topic turns out not to be deleted when I create it once again (by writing a record into the topics). In this case, Kafka throws `UnknownTopicOrPartitionException`.

I wonder if there is some way to enforce Kafka delete the topic (or at least to increase the chances of deletion).

I'll be grateful for any advice.

I'm using Kafka 0.11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete the topic in order to discard "old" data. You could achieve that by stopping Kafka server, deleting the topic's log directories, and starting the Kafka again.

A topic's directories are found inside the log directory, as specified by `log.dir` in the broker's configuration, with a prefix of the topic's name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that stopping and restarting the Kafka broker and Zookeeper server for each test dramatically increases the execution time of the tests. Maybe I could avoid this rebooting somehow?

Comment: You don't have to restart Zookeeper, but I think you need to restart Kafka in order to let it refresh its file handles.